# Photoshop bug with drop shadow

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have several layers using drop shadow that is suppose to have different angles. But whenever I change or add a drop shadow all others gets changed too, to the same angle.

Is this a bug or is there an option to stop this very annoying behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why when I change a drop shadow do all my drop shadows change?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/74725/why-when-i-change-a-drop-shadow-do-all-my-drop-shadows-change)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely `Global light` setting. Global light affects each layer with a `drop shadow` that has global light enabled.

It's right below the opacity input: "Use Global Light". You'll need to disable it for all the drop shadows you want to point to a different angle.

[image]

---

Drop shadow is not the only layer style that has global light option.